# How to select html5 range's pseudo-elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is it possible to select `<input type="range">` pseudo-elements with JS?

I can style elements like `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track` in my css, but what if I want to change `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`'s `background-color` after some event (like button click or whatever)?

Is it possible? Browsers support didn't make sense for now.

**UPD**: The question is how to style range's pseudo elements via JS.
Let's say that I need to change range's track color dynamically.
I can't just style it with `css`.

What I really need to is something like

```
document.getelementById('id').getPseudoElementSomehow('-webkit-slider-runnable-track').style = 'background: green'
```

Comment: see this link : https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: Are you wanting to get all inputs with that type via JS to then manipulate/interact with those inputs in a script, or are you wanting a way to select them via CSS selector? And if it's the latter, what exactly are you wanting to style about the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't directly select pseudo elements with Javascript. The only solution is to add css rules on the expected events with [`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = function() {
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track { background-color: red; }', 0);
};
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
<button>click me</button>
```